# Magento 2 : Is possible to use the custom collection in existing datasource for ui Component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have created one UiComponent form using one datasource. Now i want to add the custom field inside this form but this field data will come from separate collection. So how can i use the different source for this new field?

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by editing FormDataProvider

The FormDataProvider UI component is a data provider for the Form component. It stores form data in a specific format that is shared among all UI components in the scope of Form component and provides the functionality for submitting the data.

Here's a example

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Module All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Model\CollectionFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Model\CustomCollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        CustomCollectionFactory $customCollectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->customCollectionFactory = $customCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            //get data from your  custom collection 
            $customData = $this->customCollectionFactory->addFieldToFilter('model_id', $model->getId())
                                                        ->getFirstItem()
                                                        ->getData();
            //merge with current model data
            $dataToAdd = array_merge($model->getData(),$customData);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $dataToAdd;
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('vendor_module_model');
        
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('vendor_module_model');
        }
        
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

[How and where data providers are created.](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/creat-a-ui-form-in-magento-2.html#step-1)